# mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in

Tags: php, mysql

I'm building a search within my site.
I have a problem with the DB. It's giving me this:

```
Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-5.3.5.0\www\searchscript\search.php on line 86
```

I'll show you the code section where it gives me such error

```
line 82: $query = "SELECT * FROM dreams WHERE titolo,titch LIKE \"%$trimmed%\" ORDER BY id_dreams DESC "; 
line 85: $numresults=mysql_query($query);
line 86: $numrows=mysql_num_rows($numresults); //error
```

Now I tried to see what is the problem behind the query and it's telling me this:

```
SELECT * FROM dreams WHERE titolo, titch LIKE "%tags%" ORDER BY id_dreams DESC
```

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'titch LIKE "%tags%" ORDER BY id_dreams DESC' at line 1

**The code behind this is:**

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM dreams WHERE titolo, titch LIKE \"%$trimmed%\" ORDER BY id_dreams DESC "; 
$result = mysql_query($query) or die($query."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());
```

Comment: have you tried your query manually..? is it working good ??

Comment: Sick and tired of these questions. **There are a million duplicates.** Perform a search next time or just bother to look a little to the right, where they're all listed for you.

Answer (score 16):

The mysql_query is returning a boolean value meaning the sql query is probably failing and you're getting a false returned rather than a mysql resource.

Have you checked your query?

Comment: My problem is that the query is working when I perform it for one single field, though it returns me a boolean result and therefore False if I perform the search on 2 fields.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to check whether `$num_results` is a MySQL result resource. In this case your query errored, so it's `FALSE` instead.

Re-read [the documentation for `mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) and ensure you program for *all* possible cases.